# What is the history behind the factors of 3 in the classification of electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, waves, history, frequency

What is the history behind the factors of 3 in the classification of electromagnetic radiation?

See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_spectrum#By_frequency

Is this (just) inherited from the meter unit via the wavelenght frequency dependence or light?

Comment: most likely yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, the 3 is an approximation to 2.99792458 (the number of meters light travels in 10 nanoseconds), as the boundaries of the wavelength perfectly fit the metric scheme.

Comment: @LarryHarson: I agree, but you should be aware of the sqrt(10) business does fit with half-way logs. It's a coincidence of the speed of light in this case, but perhaps not elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's just an approximation to 3.1623 (the square root of 10) which is what happens if you make a log-bin in base 10 and split it into regions which include powers of 10 with the most padding, so that you divide the log-region into 1.5-5.5, so that you are 100% sure where all the integer powers of 10, 1,2,3,4,5 go.

Comment: It is far more likely to be just an approximation to 299,792,458 (the number of meters light travels in a second), as the boundaries of the wavelength perfectly fit the metric scheme.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: Oh, maybe! That's a better answer--- why don't you post it.

Comment: -1 well this is completely wrong

Comment: @LarryHarson: I agree, and it is good that you point it out. I would downvote my answer, but I can't. I don't want to delete it, because although it is wrong, I think it adds something to this question (although it's not that deep a question).